# match part of a string until it reaches the end of the line (python regex)

Tags: python, regex

If I have a large string with multiple lines and I want to match part of a line only to end of that line, what is the best way to do that?

So, for example I have something like this and I want it to stop matching when it reaches the new line character.

```
r"(?P<name>[A-Za-z\s.]+)"
```

I saw this in a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822323/regex-match-the-text-before-the-end-of-line):

> $ - indicates matching to the end of the string, or end of a line if
>   multiline is enabled.

My question is then how do you "enable multiline" as the author of that answer states?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply use

```
r"(?P<name>[A-Za-z\t .]+)"
```

This will match ASCII letters, spaces, tabs or periods. It'll stop at the first character that's not included in the group - and newlines aren't (whereas they *are* included in `\s`, and because of that it's irrelevant whether multiline mode is turned on or off).

Answer (score 2):

You can enable multiline matching by passing `re.MULTILINE` as the second argument to `re.compile()`. However, there is a subtlety to watch out for: since the `+` quantifier is greedy, this regular expression will match as long a string as possible, so if the next line is made up of letters and whitespace, the regex might match more than one line (`$` matches the end of *any* string).

There are three solutions to this:

1. Change your regex so that, instead of matching any whitespace including newline (`\s`) your repeated character set does not match that newline.
2. Change the quantifier to `+?`, the non-greedy ("minimal") version of `+`, so that it will match as short a string as possible and therefore stop at the *first* newline.
3. Change your code to first split the text up into an individual string for each line (using `text.split('\n')`.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions!  The first one sounds the easiest to implement.  Do you know specifically how I can specify I only want single spaces to be matched as opposed to any whitespace?  I tried the second solution but it only matches a single character.

Comment: My bad, should have mentioned - for all these solutions, you should also include the `$` (end of string) anchor at the end. That way, with solution 2, `re` will find the shortest string that matches the regex *and* goes up to the end of a line, which is what you want. For solution 1, a space can be represented in a character set by a literal space - no escaping required (i.e. `[A-Za-z .]`)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `flags` parameter at http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#module-contents

Comment: This is not helpful - enabling multiline mode will not solve his problem.

Comment: Right, and if someone asks you if he should hold his hammer upwards or downwards to drive in a screw, you wouldn't tell him to use a screwdriver instead :)